# The difference between jailing, sandboxing and interpretation

Tags: sandbox

In my IT security classes I frequently ran over these terms and had a hard time distinguishing between them, so I tried to figure their differences:

**Sandboxing**: Defense mechanism against *mobile code*, which runs in a separate runtime environment. Code and data are separated to prevent the program from modifying itself. This is used for small applications like applets in  the JVM.

**Interpretation**: Defense mechanism against *mobile code*. Direct access to hardware is prevented and all addresses and system calls are interpreted and analyzed. Web browsers use this technique at the expense of performance.

**Jailing**: Defense mechanism against an *unknown program*. All system calls of a supervised program prisoner are checked by another program jailer who can also intercept and block them.

Are these definitions valid or are there any more differences / similarities which I didn't see? Especially some real world scenarios would be helpful, for example I know that sandboxing is used in the JVM as part of Java security.

Comment: browsers use sandboxing, not interpretation...

Comment: 10 years ago browsers used interpretation for JavaScript, but that is much slower. Now they JIT compile JavaScript and use Sandboxing.

Answer (score 2):

I hear in these terms an attempt to explain at a higher level of abstraction a continuum of ways to approach the problem of hosting executable code on a system you wish to protect.

1. Native: allow executable code to run normally on the target system with full rights and privileges of other code on the system
2. Jail: allow executable code to run normally on the target system except that access to sensitive resources- from specific syscalls to specific APIs to resources like disk or network i/o- whatever is appropriate for the context- is blocked in some fashion. Think of this as a blacklist- a policy of default allow with specific deny rules.
3. Sandbox: a more restrictive environment than a Jail. Executable code runs in an abstraction of the target system, though some limited direct access to sensitive resources is allowed. Think of this as a whitelist- a policy of default deny (well, default abstracted/faked) with some specific allow rules.
4. Interpret: is a poor term for the concept, which represents the other end of the spectrum from Native. Executable code is run in a completely abstracted environment with no direct interaction at all with resources on the target system. A better term may be "Simulated."

Hope that helps.